# what does mean this exception ? format %d expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'long long unsigned int' [-Wformat]

Tags: c, printf, sizeof, size-t, conversion-specifier

I'm a student trying to learn C and C++, I've got a problem with the specifier %d I dont't understand the exception that is written in the console, It's writing

```
The format %d expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'long long unsigned int' [-Wformat]
```

Here is the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    short int u=1;
    int v=2;
    long int w=3;
    char x='x';
    float y=4;
    double z=5;
    long double a=6;
    long b=7;
    printf("short int:%d\n",sizeof(u));
    printf("int:%d octets\n",sizeof(v));
    printf("long int:%d octets\n",sizeof(w));
    printf("char:%d octets\n",sizeof(x));
    printf("float:%d octets\n",sizeof(y));
    printf("double:%d octets\n",sizeof(z));
    printf("long double:%d octets\n",sizeof(a));
    printf("long:%d octets\n",sizeof(b));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the result of `sizeof` is of type `size_t`, which on your system is equivalent to a Long Long Unsigned.  Instead of `%d`, you should use `%zu` which is meant for arguments of type `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the value returned by the operator `sizeof` is the unsigned integer type `size_t` The conversion specifier `d` is used to output values of the type `int`. You have to use the conversion specifier `zu`. Otherwise you will get undefined behavior.

For example

```
printf("short int:%zu\n",sizeof(u));
```

From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> 9 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
> undefined.275) **If any argument is not the correct type for the
> corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.**

Answer (score 1):

The [`sizeof` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) returns a `size_t` type. This is always unsigned and, on your platform, is a `long long unsigned int`; on other platforms, it may be just `unsigned long` or, indeed, some other (unsigned) integer type.

Use the `%zu` format specifier for arguments of this type; this will work *whatever* the actual `size_t` type definition happens to be.